# How to fix ajv schema not being checked correctly while testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ajv

Basically I am currently writing a unit test for a function which checks if a `json`-file is valid, using an AJV Schema. The problem is, that the checking against the schema works in the browser, but not in the test.

InvalidFileError

```
export class InvalidFileError extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message)
        this.name = "InvalidFileError"
    }
}
```

The function I'm trying to test

```
export function importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.readAsText(file)

    fileReader.onload = () => { // File loaded
        const fileContent = JSON.parse(fileReader.result)

        const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true})
        const validate = ajv.compile(schema)
        const contentIsValid = validate(fileContent)

        console.log("Content is valid: ", contentIsValid)
        if (contentIsValid) {
            importScenarios(fileContent.scenarios)
            importDevices(fileContent.devices)
        } else {
            throw new InvalidFileError("This file doesn't match the schema")
        }
    }
}
```

The current test I have written

```
describe("Does Importing a file work properly?", () => {
    let file
    let e = {
        target: {
            files: []
        }
    }

    let importScenarios = () => {}
    let importDevices = () => {}

    test("Does it work with a file matching the schema?", () => {
        file = new Blob(correctTestContent, { type: "application/json" })

        e.target.files.push(file)
        expect(() => {
            FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices)
        }).not.toThrow(InvalidFileError)
    })

    test("Does it work with a file not matching the schema??", () => {
        file = new Blob(incorrectTestContent, { type: "application/json" })
        e.target.files.push(file)

        expect(() => {
            FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices)
        }).toThrow(InvalidFileError)
    })

    afterEach(() => {
        e.target.files = []
    })
})
```

When I use this function in the browser, by uploading an invalid file, it throws an error, and it if i upload a valid file, it does not.
This should be the exact same in the test, but unfortunately it is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the code you are trying to test is asynchronous, while the tests you have written are not.

When you run the tests, the `onload` callback of the `FileReader` is not being executed during the execution of the corresponding test. Instead, it is being called after the test has executed. In fact, because you have the statement:

```
console.log("Content is valid: ", contentIsValid)
```

inside the `importFile` method, you should be seeing in console a message like this one:

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something async in your test?

You need to make your tests [asynchronous](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous), so that they wait for the `onload` callback execution. Unfortunately, your code is difficult to test as it is, because you have no way to know when the `onload` callback has been executed so it is also difficult to wait in the test until that moment.

One way to solve this problem would be to wrap your asynchronous code in a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and return it so that we can wait until the promise is finished. With this approach, your `importFile` would look something like:

```
export function importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
    const fileReader = new FileReader()
    fileReader.readAsText(file)

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fileReader.onload = () => { // File loaded
            const fileContent = JSON.parse(fileReader.result)

            const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true})
            const validate = ajv.compile(schema)
            const contentIsValid = validate(fileContent)

            if (contentIsValid) {
                importScenarios(fileContent.scenarios)
                importDevices(fileContent.devices)
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject(new InvalidFileError("This file doesn't match the schema"))
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then, you can test this method by returning the Promise in the test (so that jest knows that it has to wait until the promise is resolved or rejected):

```
let importScenarios = jest.fn()
let importDevices = jest.fn()

test("Does it work with a file matching the schema?", () => {
    expect.assertions(2);

    file = new Blob(correctTestContent, { type: "application/json" })
    e.target.files.push(file)

    return FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices).then(() => {
        expect(importScenarios).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(importDevices).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});

test('Does it work with a file not matching the schema??', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    file = new Blob(incorrectTestContent, { type: "application/json" })
    e.target.files.push(file)

    return FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices).catch((e) => {
        expect(e).toBeInstanceOf(InvalidFileError);
    });
});
```

Note that I have redefined the variables `importScenarios` and `importDevices` so that they are [mock functions](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions) and we can check if they are called. Also, note the use of `expect.assertions` to verify that a certain number of assertions are called.

Lastly, take into account that if you redefine your `importFile` so that it returns a promise, you'll likely have to change the places where you call it to treat the rejection case. Where you have:

```
try {
    FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices)
} catch(e) {
    // Some treatment of your exception
}
```

you will need:

```
FileManager.importFile(e, importScenarios, importDevices).catch(e => {
    // Some treatment of your exception
})
```

Comment: Hey mgarcia, 
Thanks for your answer! 
Unfortunately, when I make these alterations, in the test console, it now prints this line: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:`
Also, now in the user interface, when I try to import a file which doesn't match the schema, it imports it either way, without logging a caught error message in the console

Comment: Correction: the last part about the interface was a mistake i made, importing incorrect files, does in fact log the error

Comment: I did try increasing the jest timeout to 30 seconds to see if that would change anything, but it gave the same error, but now with `30000ms` instead of the initial `5000ms`

Comment: It seems that something is not being called in your code, probably due to a typo. Are you returning the promise both in your `importFile` function and your test? Are you calling the `resolve` method inside `importFile` when the validation is right?